# Can McAfee run on non-admin users without prompting for admin access?

Tags: macos, administrator

i am facing a issue in one of my macbookPro which is integrated into a windows environment. i have McAfee installed its asking for administrator credential every time another user login in(who does not have admin access).
any way we could grant admin access to those user for McAfee only so the popup doesn`t come up or something else that could fix the problem.